# Deriving potential from central force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, potential, potential-energy, integration

I've read in a book that for a central force of the form $$ f(r)= \frac{{-ke^ {-r/a}}}{r^2} $$ the adequate potential is $$ V(r)= \frac{{-ke^ {-r/a}}}{r} $$

I'm trying to understand why $$ -\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{r}}=f(r) $$
I've tried checking in wolfram and some other sites, but still can't figure it out. I thought perhaps there's some assumption being made that eliminates the second element in the derivative of V, but can't think of something.
can someone please help me understand how to integrate this thing?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to integrate $f(r)$ to obtain $V(r)$?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28r%29%3D%28-k+e%5E%28-r%2Fa%29%29%2Fr%5E2 Wolfram alpha exceeds standard computation time.

Comment: A strange thing here is that $f(r) \neq -V'(r)$.

Comment: @Gec I saw it in few places (few different books) and I can't understand why it's true. I thought maybe there's some assumption that's being made in order to eliminate the second element?

Comment: if $a\rightarrow\infty$ then the equation $ -\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}=f(r)$ holds

Comment: may be they mean k'=k-1/a for the potential

Comment: What book? Are you certain that you have included all of the contextual assumptions?

Comment: For small values of r the $\frac{1}{r}$ term would be negligable compared to the $\frac{1}{r^2}$ term in the derivative of V so that could be it

Comment: The fact that they refer to the potential as being adequate suggests to me that in the context where you see this formula used, the “a” in the denominator of the second term of the derivative is very large compared with the “r”, so that the second term is negligible compared with the first.

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: It’s either wrong or it is some approximation.

Comment: @Gec can you expound on why this is?

Comment: Possible duplicates:https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/568164/2451

Comment: @LopeyTall, I thought it is obvious: $(-ke^{-r/a}/r)' = ke^{-r/a}/r^2 + ke^{-r/a}/ra \neq  ke^{-r/a}/r^2$.

Comment: @Gec but WHY is this the case? Why do you even write $\neq ke^{-r/a}/r^2$? Where is this expression coming from? I am asking because I'm running into trouble studying Bertand's Theorem in the case of the Yukawa potential

Comment: @LopeyTall, I do not understand what is unclear. As the topic starter says, he tries to understand why $f(r) = -V'(r)$, while for the $f(r)$ and $V(r)$ given we have $f(r) \neq -V'(r)$.